# Number operator - annihilation operator commutation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, commutator

Is there a rigorous way to prove that
$$
(N+1)^{-1/2} a = a N^{-1/2}
$$
where $a$ is a bosonic annihilation operator and $N=a^\dagger a$ is the corresponding number operator?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the action of the two operators on an arbitrary number state $|n\rangle$:

- for the left-hand side,
  \begin{align}
  (N+1)^{-1/2}a|n\rangle
    & = (N+1)^{-1/2}\sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle
      = \sqrt{n}(N+1)^{-1/2}|n-1\rangle
  \\& = \sqrt{n}(n-1+1)^{-1/2}|n-1\rangle
      = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}|n-1\rangle
  \\& = |n-1\rangle,
  \end{align}
- whereas on the right-hand side
  \begin{align}
  aN^{-1/2}|n\rangle
  & = a \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}|n\rangle
    = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} a |n\rangle
    = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sqrt{n} |n-1\rangle
  \\& = |n-1\rangle.
  \end{align}

Since the two operators agree on a basis, they are equal as operators.